# How to properly chain Perl substitutions

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I notice that when directly in terminal it is easy to chain substitutions together:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\xa/\xd/g; s/(<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t)([A-Z\.]{15,})(\r\t.+)/\2/g' _temp.txt;
```

However, I am not having success combining two substitutions together as I do a rewrite of some scripting I have. Currently, as two separate statements, it works, but I am not sure how to combine these two lines together:

```
$thisGrid =~ s/\xa/\xd/g;
$thisGrid =~ s/(<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t)([A-Z\.]{15,})(\r\t.+)/\2/g;
```

First I tried:

```
$thisGrid =~ s/\xa/\xd/g =~ s/(<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t)([A-Z\.]{15,})(\r\t.+)/\2/g;
```

This did not seem to work.

Other similar threads did not seem to answer my question.

Comment: In the `-e` code there are also two "lines" in terms of commands/statements, note the `;`. You can also remove the newline in the script, to have it one "line" in terms of text lines, if you want. Though it's worse to read then... The question is what you want actually want to achieve here? What do you hope happens if there's no new line in between?

Comment: As [sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit) indicated perl _oneliner_ uses two separate commands to make substitution  -- `;` says perform left part then right part. There is no advantage of chaining except a case if first produces result _true_ and only then perform second -- `s/old/new/ if s/very_old/newer/;` or `s/very_old/newer/ && s/old/new`. Your case does not _fall_ in such category -- code is _linear_: perform first substitution then second substitution.

Comment: Also it is not clear why you use `s/(<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t)([A-Z\.]{15,})(\r\t.+)/\2/g` instead of `s/<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t([A-Z\.]{15,})\r\t.+/\1/g`. What is the purpose of _extra_ brackets if result is not used anywhere else?

Comment: Documentation [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) discourages of use `\1` as it can lead to unexpected outcome.

Comment: The syntax is `$new_string = $old_string =~ s/foo/bar/gr =~ s/blah/baz/gr`.

Comment: OK, thanks to all. I had asked the question, as I am not a Perl guru, but I know that Perl has the ability to be highly compact. I just thought maybe since Perl was able to chain under some circumstances, it might also work for my rewrite.

Comment: `s/foo/bar/g, s/bar/quux/g for $thisGrid`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A foreach loop can be used as a topicalizer.

```
for ($thisGrid) {
   s/\x0A/\x0D/g;
   s/(?:<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t)([A-Z\.]{15,})(?:\r\t.+)/$1/g; 
}
```

Otherwise, you need to use `/r` to return the modified string.

```
$thisGrid =
   $thisGrid
   =~ s/\x0A/\x0D/gr
   =~ s/(?:<ACROSS PUZZLE>.+<GRID>\r\t)([A-Z\.]{15,})(?:\r\t.+)/$1/gr;
```

You can chain them